# Can IFTTT take an existing RSS feed and generate new feeds (plural) based on some criteria. If not, what options exist?

Tags: web-applications, rss, ifttt

I have an existing RSS, not generated or hosted or controlled by me, and I want to create new RSS feeds (plural) based on sub string matching on some field.

So: given feed Fruits, I want to create two new feeds Apples and Oranges. Whenever an item containing the string 'apple' in the title is added to feed Fruits, I want it automatically added to feed Apples, and likewise for 'orange'. People who like apples can subscribe to Apples, people who like oranges can subscribe to Oranges. Apples and Oranges  should be updated in reasonable time (1 day) after Fruits is updated.

Can this be done using IFTTT (I haven't gotten into IFTTT at all, I'd just like to know if it is possible so I can investigate).  If IFTTT can't do it, what are some other options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [*Inoreader*](http://Inoreader.com).  It’s an RSS service that has many powerful features, including the ability to create RSS feeds and run rules that trigger in response to various conditions.  It also has an API that you can access to control your feeds programmatically.  It’s free, but the paid-for service will give you access to these features aimed at “power users”.  It can definitely achieve what you’re describing.  Let me know if you want me to post an answer laying out how one would go about this in *Inoreader*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for inoreader. The solution I went with was to use IFTTT to detect change in the feed, then call my own php script  (I already have a web host) to process and generate the custom feeds I need.